# How to match two columns from a DataFrame (including Arrays) with two columns from a CSV (Dataframe/Dictionary)

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

I have a DataFrame like this;

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  [["Apple"],['iPhone EE','iPhone 11', 'iPhone 11 Pro']],   
  [["Acer"],['Iconia Talk S','liquid Z6 Plus']],   
  [["Casio"],['Casio G\'zOne Brigade']],
  [["Alcatel"[,[]],
  [["HTC", "Honor"].["Play 4", "Play 7"]]
]).toDF("brand","type")
```

And a csv like this;

```
Apple;iPhone EE
Apple;iPhone 11 Pro
Apple;iPhone XS
Acer;liquid Z6 Plus
Acer;Acer Predator 8
Casio;Casio G'zOne Ravine
Alcatel;3L
HTC;Play 4
Honor;Play 7
```

I need to create a new boolean column `match`.
If the combination of `brand` **and** `type` matches one of the rows from the CSV it's `True` otherwise `False`.

Expected output:

```
    Brand      | Type                                  | Match
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    Apple      | [iPhone EE, iPhone 11, iPhone 11 Pro] | True
    Acer       | [Iconia Talk S, liquid Z6 Plus]       | True
    Casio      | [Casio G\'zOne Brigade]               | False
    Alcatel    | []                                    | False
    HTC, Honor | [Play 4, Play 7]                      | True
```

**Update

`brand` is also of type `array<string>`**

The csv file is just a start. it can be converted to a Dataframe or Dictionary (or whatever fits best).

How can I best accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [size](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.size) + [array_intersect](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_intersect) to set up this flag.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_set, size, array_intersect, broadcast, expr, flatten, collect_list, array_join

df_list = spark.read.csv("/path/to/csv_list", sep=';').toDF('brand_name','type')

df1 = df_list.groupby('brand_name').agg(collect_set('type').alias('types'))
  
df_new = df.join(broadcast(df1), expr("array_contains(brand, brand_name)"), "left") \
    .groupby('brand', 'Type') \
    .agg(flatten(collect_list('types')).alias('types')) \
    .select(array_join('brand', ', ').alias('brand'), 'Type', (size(array_intersect('type', 'types'))>0).alias("Match"))

df_new.show(5,0)
+----------+-------------------------------------+-----+                        
|brand     |Type                                 |Match|
+----------+-------------------------------------+-----+
|Alcatel   |[]                                   |false|
|HTC, Honor|[Play 4, Play 7]                     |true |
|Casio     |[Casio G'zOne Brigade]               |false|
|Acer      |[Iconia Talk S, liquid Z6 Plus]      |true |
|Apple     |[iPhone EE, iPhone 11, iPhone 11 Pro]|true |
+----------+-------------------------------------+-----+
```

**Method-2:** using Map (`map<string,array<string>>`):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import arrays_overlap, array, lit, col, create_map, col, monotonically_increasing_id, first, explode, array_join

dict1 = df1.rdd.collectAsMap()

map1 = create_map([ t for k,v in dict1.items() for t in [lit(k), array(*map(lit,v))] ])
#Column<b"map(Casio, array(Casio G'zOne Ravine), Alcatel, array(3L), Acer, array(Acer Predator 8, liquid Z6 Plus), HTC, array(Play 4), Honor, array(Play 7), Apple, array(iPhone EE, iPhone 11 Pro, iPhone XS))">

df_new = df.withColumn('id', monotonically_increasing_id()) \
  .withColumn('brand', explode('brand')) \
  .withColumn('Match', arrays_overlap('type', map1[col('brand')])) \
  .groupby('id') \
  .agg(
    array_join(collect_set('brand'),', ').alias('brand'),
    first('Type').alias('Type'),
    expr("sum(int(Match)) > 0 as Match")
)

df_new.show(5,0)                                                                                                    
+---+----------+-------------------------------------+-----+
|id |brand     |Type                                 |Match|
+---+----------+-------------------------------------+-----+
|0  |Apple     |[iPhone EE, iPhone 11, iPhone 11 Pro]|true |
|1  |Acer      |[Iconia Talk S, liquid Z6 Plus]      |true |
|3  |Alcatel   |[]                                   |false|
|2  |Casio     |[Casio G'zOne Brigade]               |false|
|4  |HTC, Honor|[Play 4, Play 7]                     |true |
+---+----------+-------------------------------------+-----+
```

Comment: I must apologize. Brand is also of type array<string>. Can you please help me with to change Method-1 ?

Comment: update added to reflect your latest change including the csv list.

Comment: I get an error with `df_new = df.join(broadcast(df1), expr("array_contains(brand, brand_name)"), "left")` `cannot resolve 'array_contains (....) due to data type mismatch: Input to function array_contains should have been array followed by a value with same element type, but it's [array<string>, array<string>]`
It looks like they are both the same type `array<string>`. I Also checked with `printSchema()` and they're both of type `array<string>`.

Comment: how did you setup df1? if you followed the step in my post, we read the df_list from csv file and after groupby, `brand_name` should be a StringType? unless you have some other post-processing steps?

Comment: Changing the order fixed it ...duh `expr("array_contains(brand, brand_name)")` and I used `expr("array_contains(brand_name, brand)")`

Answer (score 1):

this might be useful.

```
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F

>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([
...   ["Apple",['iPhone EE','iPhone 11', 'iPhone 11 Pro']],   
...   ["Acer",['Iconia Talk S','liquid Z6 Plus']],   
...   ["Casio",['Casio G\'zOne Brigade']],
...   ["Alcatel",[]]
... ]).toDF("brand","type")
>>> df.show(df.count(), False)
+-------+-------------------------------------+
|brand  |type                                 |
+-------+-------------------------------------+
|Apple  |[iPhone EE, iPhone 11, iPhone 11 Pro]|
|Acer   |[Iconia Talk S, liquid Z6 Plus]      |
|Casio  |[Casio G'zOne Brigade]               |
|Alcatel|[]                                   |
+-------+-------------------------------------+

>>> file_df = sqlcontext.read.csv('/home/chai/brand.csv', header='true')
>>> file_df.show(file_df.count(), False)
+-------+-------------------+
|brand  |types              |
+-------+-------------------+
|Apple  |iPhone EE          |
|Apple  |iPhone 11 Pro      |
|Apple  |iPhone XS          |
|Acer   |liquid Z6 Plus     |
|Acer   |Acer Predator 8    |
|Casio  |Casio G'zOne Ravine|
|Alcatel|3L                 |
+-------+-------------------+

>>> file_df = file_df.groupBy('brand').agg(F.collect_list('types').alias('new'))
>>> file_df.show(file_df.count(), False)
+-------+-------------------------------------+
|brand  |new                                  |
+-------+-------------------------------------+
|Casio  |[Casio G'zOne Ravine]                |
|Alcatel|[3L]                                 |
|Acer   |[liquid Z6 Plus, Acer Predator 8]    |
|Apple  |[iPhone EE, iPhone 11 Pro, iPhone XS]|
+-------+-------------------------------------+

>>> def test(row_dict):
...     new_dict = dict()
...     for i in row_dict.get('type'):
...             if i in row_dict.get('new'):
...                     new_dict['flag'] = 'True'
...             else:
...                     new_dict['flag'] = 'False'
...     if len(row_dict.get('type')) == 0 and len(row_dict.get('new')) > 0:
...             new_dict['flag'] = 'False'
...     new_dict['brand'] = row_dict.get('brand')
...     new_dict['type'] = row_dict.get('type')
...     new_dict['new'] = row_dict.get('new')
...     return new_dict
... 
>>> def row_to_dict(row):
...     return row.asDict(recursive=True)
>>> rdd = all.rdd.map(row_to_dict)
>>> rdd1 = rdd.map(test)
>>> final_df = sqlcontext.createDataFrame(rdd1)
>>> final_df.show(final_df.count(), False)
+-------+-----+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|brand  |flag |new                                  |type                                 |
+-------+-----+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|Apple  |True |[iPhone EE, iPhone 11 Pro, iPhone XS]|[iPhone EE, iPhone 11, iPhone 11 Pro]|
|Acer   |True |[liquid Z6 Plus, Acer Predator 8]    |[Iconia Talk S, liquid Z6 Plus]      |
|Casio  |False|[Casio G'zOne Ravine]                |[Casio G'zOne Brigade]               |
|Alcatel|False|[3L]                                 |[]                                   |
+-------+-----+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```